# Can I detect (and warn on) redundancies at compile time?

Tags: c++

Is there any way I can catch and warn about redundancies at compile time?

Such as

```
if (abc && abc)
```

or

```
if (def || def)
```

---

Ok, this isn't actually from an optimisation point of view - I'm thinking more along the lines of a mistake in code - so when the coder intended to write

```
if (abc && abc)
```

when actually they meant to write

```
if (abc && def)
```

The compiler is going to silently optimise away the mistake, whereas I actually want to know if I can get the compiler to warn me if that has happened, in case it's in there by mistake!

Comment: Do you often write code like that?

Comment: Do you want to detect "if (TRUE)" as well? Are you trying to detect expressions that are reducible to simpler ones, expressions that are always true/false, or unreachable code?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: As I understend that are examples. Imagine that you have `happy(X) :- dragon(X), fly(X)` and `green(X) :- dragon(X), not(orange(X))` - i.e. something is happy if it is a dragon and flies and it is green if it is a dragon and not orange. If you want to check if something is happy and green (`happy(X), green(X)`) you have `dragon(X), fly(X), dragon(X), not(orange(X))`. But `dragon(X)` is duplicated  and if it is pure can be ommited. however writing `happy(X), green(X)` gives more information about what we want to check (sorry for using prolog - `,` means `&&`).

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: >> Do you often write code like that?

No, not often, but I'm only human, and I make mistakes.  I'd like a machine to be able to warn me when I've potentially made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a tool that statically checks for dubious-looking code, you most likely need some form of [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)). Industrial-strength lint implementations check for many, many things--I don't know if it will check for the kind of redundancy you gave as an example, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

First, those technically aren't tautologies, they're redundancies. Tautology means it's always true, for example

```
if (abc || !abc)
```

And for catching them - you don't have to do anything, any compiler worth it's salt will optimize that away for you. But I sure hope you don't actually have code like that.

Comment: If it's a basic type it can be optimized away, but if abc is an object with a boolean or numeric cast operator defined then the compiler shouldn't optimize it since there's no guarantee that the cast will return the same value if called twice.

Answer (score 2):

Set your compiler to maximum warning level. Check the warnings.

Comment: Why would you expect a warning? What's wrong with the code?
(from the code point of view)

Comment: It is pretty obvious why such warnings can be useful, since it probably was not the programmer's intent to write code like that and probably indicates a typo or cut & paste error. To be useful, the compiler would probably need to distinguish between cases typed by the programmer and those that are the result of macro expansion.

Answer (score 2):

A good compiler will take care of this for you, if you compile with optimization turned on. With gcc, for instance, your first example compiles to (no optimization):

```
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $8, %esp
    cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)
    je      L2
    cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)   ; checking abc again!
    je      L2
      ...      
L2:
```

whereas with optimization turned on, the second compare goes away:

```
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $8, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne     L4
    leave
    ret
L4:
      ...
```

Comment: What are you declaring abc to be?  The compiler shouldn't optimize out anything other than a basic type.